# Understanding the differences between pid_max, ulimit -u and thread_max

Tags: linux-kernel, process, ulimit, thread

I am trying to understand the Linux processes. I'm confused on the respective terms `pid_max`, `ulimit -u` and `thread_max`.

What exactly is the difference between these terms? Can someone clarify the differences?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let us understand the difference between a process and a thread. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200469/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-and-a-thread) link,

> The typical difference is that threads (of the same process) run in a
>   shared memory space, while processes run in separate memory spaces.

Now, we have the `pid_max` parameter which can be determined as below.

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
```

So the above command returns **32,768** which means I can execute **32,768** processes simultaneously in my system that can run in separate memory spaces.

Now, we have the `threads-max` parameter which can be determined as below.

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

The above command returns me the output as **126406** which means I can have **126406** threads in a shared memory space.

Now, let us take the 3rd parameter `ulimit -u` which says the total processes a user can have at a particular time. The above command returns me the output as **63203**. This means for all the processes that a user has created at a point of time the user can have **63203** processes running.

**Hypothetical case**

So assuming there are 2 processes simultaneously being run by 2 users and each process is consuming memory heavily, both the processes will effectively use the **63203** user limit on the processes. So, if that is the case, the 2 users will have effectively used up the entire **126406** `threads-max` size.

Now, I need to determine how many processes an user can run at any point of time. This can be determined from the file, `/etc/security/limits.conf`. So, there are basically 2 settings in this file as explained over [here](http://gerardnico.com/wiki/linux/limits.conf).

A *soft limit* is like a **warning** and *hard limit* is a **real max limit**. For example, following will prevent anyone in the student group from having more than 50 processes, and a warning will be given at 30 processes.

```
@student        hard    nproc           50
@student        soft    nproc           30
```

Hard limits are maintained by the kernel while the soft limits are enforced by the shell.

Comment: I guess you have mentioned wrongly that `ulimit -u` denotes maximum `threads` a user can have, but actually it means the maximum `processes` a user can have.

Comment: @KannanMohan, I think you are right. When I checked the man page, it showed up as process only. I will try and change the answer in sometime. Thanks for letting me know. I appreciate it.

Comment: I've edited the answer to fix the references of `ulimit -u` being associated with threads to being associated with processes.

Comment: There is a small connection between "max user processes" and threads. It limits the amount of "native" threads that user is allowed to have. For example use 3 java processes to open 500 threads each assuming that "max user processes" is 1000. Then try to run java -version and see the JVM crush miserably

Answer (score 23):

Sorry, the accepted answer is bad information on several fronts.

`/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` has nothing to do with the maximum number of processes that can be run at any given time.  It is, in fact, the maximum numerical PROCESS IDENTIFIER than can be assigned by the kernel.

In the Linux kernel, a process and a thread are one and the same.  They're handled the same way by the kernel.  They both occupy a slot in the task_struct data structure.  A thread, by common terminology, is in Linux a process that shares resources with another process (they will also share a thread group ID).  A thread in the Linux kernel is largely a conceptual construct as far as the scheduler is concerned.

Now that you understand that the kernel largely does not differentiate between a thread and a process, it should make more sense that `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` is actually the maximum number of elements contained in the data structure task_struct.  Which is the data structure that contains the list of processes, or as they can be called, tasks.

ulimit is, as the name implies, a per-user limit.  The `-u` flag is defined as "The maximum number of processes available to a single user".  An element of task_struct contains the uid of the user that created the task.  A per-uid count is maintained and incremented/decremented every time a task is added/removed from task_struct.  So, `ulimit -u` indicates the maximum number of elements (processes) that one particular user is allowed to have within task_struct at any given time.

I hope that clears things up.

Comment: I feel like there is a contradiction in this answer.

"/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max has nothing to do with the maximum number of processes that can be run at any given time."

If the kernel runs out of PIDs to assign because the number of threads/procs currently running is greater than `pid_max`, doesn't that prevent creation of new threads/procs?

We hit this problem recently. The number of running threads/procs reached `pid_max`, which resulted in this error: "could not fork worker process: Resource temporarily unavailable"