# Why does Linux needs both pid_max and threads-max?

Tags: linux-kernel, process, sysctl, thread

I understand the difference between `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` and `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max`. There's a good explanation at the answer to
[Understanding the differences between pid_max, ulimit -u and thread_max](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/345052/273579):

> `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` has nothing to do with the maximum number
> of processes that can be run at any given time.  It is, in fact, the
> maximum numerical PROCESS IDENTIFIER than can be assigned by the
> kernel.
>
> In the Linux kernel, a process and a thread are one and the same.
> They're handled the same way by the kernel.  They both occupy a slot
> in the task_struct data structure.  A thread, by common terminology,
> is in Linux a process that shares resources with another process (they
> will also share a thread group ID).  A thread in the Linux kernel is
> largely a conceptual construct as far as the scheduler is concerned.
>
> Now that you understand that the kernel largely does not differentiate
> between a thread and a process, it should make more sense that
> `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` is actually the maximum number of
> elements contained in the data structure task_struct.  Which is the
> data structure that contains the list of processes, or as they can be
> called, tasks.

However, effectively, both limit the maximum number of concurrent threads on a host. This number will be - to my understanding - the minimum of `pid_max` and `threads-max`. So why are both needed?

I understand that the default value `pid_max` is [based on the number of possible CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39631072/8529284) of the machine while the default of `threads-max` is derived from the [number of pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21926745/8529284). But since both have the same effect, couldn't Linux just have one value that would be the minimum of both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These settings don’t have the same effect:

- `threads-max` limits the number of processes which can be instantiated simultaneously
- `pid_max` limits the identifier assigned to processes

`threads-max` limits the amount of memory that can end up allocated to `task_struct` instances. `pid_max` determines when pids roll around (if ever).

Constraining `pid_max` doesn’t have an effect on memory consumption (as far as I’m aware, unless lots of pids end up stored as text), and can end up affecting performance since finding a new pid is harder once `pid_max` has been reached. A lower `pid_max` also increases the likelihood of pid reuse within a given time period.

Comment: _"unless lots of pids end up stored as text"_ - what do you mean by that?

Comment: If something stores pids as strings rather than `pid_t`, then storage requirements increase with the order of magnitude of the pids; but I would be rather surprised if that ever had a significant impact.